# JDBC Issue while shifting from glassfish 3.1 to glassfish 4.0

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbctemplate, glassfish-4

Here is my Code which work fines on JSF 2.0 and Glassfish 3.1

```
 public static Connection connect(){
    try{

        String userName = "Defend";
        String password = "123456";
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=ProductDB;";
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
        System.out.println("Connected-DB");
        return con;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now when i Shift it to Glassfish 4.0 it arises the following warnings and errors

> SEVERE: Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
>   SEVERE: Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
>   SEVERE: Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
>   SEVERE: Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
>   SEVERE: Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
>   SEVERE: Unable to call @PreDestroy annotated methods because no InjectionProvider can be found. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
>   WARNING: The web application [/CyberD] registered the JDBC driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
>   SEVERE: The web application [/CyberD] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityCorrelator$1] (value [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityCorrelator$1@163a1f8f]) and a value of type [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityId] (value [1a62bb37-9aa5-4b36-8185-354eca0f8da0-3]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

as well as give NullPointerException on calling this connect() function. kindly guide me